# change simple_form to form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

hi i not long ago start to study rails

and in some screencast i saw that code strings:

```
<%= f.input :publish_date %>
<%= f.association :categories, :as => :check_boxes %>
```

and in out put i saw 
3 fields for select ( year, months, day )
and 
several checkboxes (as much as it was in the same name table)

in this video hero created new post

in migration => publish_date:date

in model => has_and_belongs_to_many :categories

and my question: help me change this form field(simple form) to normal view ( form_for )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Form Helper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html) version of your inputs are:

```
<%= f.select_date :publish_date %>

<% Category.all.each do |category| %>
  <%= check_box_tag 'video[category_ids][]', category.id %>
  <%= category.name -%>
<% end %>
```